# ERROR: INSERT has more target columns than expressions in eclipse (java)

Tags: java, postgresql, sql-insert

I need add record on database. But when i do this code.. i have a problem :(
I don't know what i do wrong :(
help

```
public void addTicket (String customersID, String agentID, String campaigns_ID) {
        String insertTicket = " INSERT INTO workforce.tickets(customers_id," + " records_id," + "assigned_agents_id," +"work_time," + "subject,"
                + "description," + "created_at," + "created_by," + "identifier," + "campaigns_id," + "new_messages," + " last_states_id)"
                                                                                + "VALUES (" + ConfigDB.customer_id_selenium + ", 4983544 ,NULL,0,'Test','''',now()," + ConfigDB.agents_selenium_id 
                + "1420610569, "+ConfigDB.campaign_ticket+",0, -1)";
```

Comment: i knoooww ! i missing "," :O

Comment: Don't concatenate SQL statements like this. You will get syntax errors if there are special characters in the variable values and you are wide open to SQL Injection attacks. Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Please format your code....

You probably want something like this:

```
String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO MyTable (StrCol1, StrCol2) VALUES (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "Val 1");
preparedStatement.setString(2, "Val 2");
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

My Friend you have missed ',' comma for

> ,work_time,subject,description 
>     value 
>   ,'Test','', ''

Please use the below code and try running the method/class

```
public void addTicket (String customersID, String agentID, String campaigns_ID) 
{ 
    String insertTicket = " INSERT INTO  "
            +"  workforce.tickets  "
            +"  (customers_id, records_id,assigned_agents_id  "
            +"  ,work_time,subject,description  "
            +"  ,created_at,created_by,identifier,campaigns_id,new_messages, last_states_id)  "
            +"  VALUES   "
            +"  ( "+ConfigDB.customer_id_selenium +" , 4983544 ,NULL,0  "
            +"  ,'Test','', ''  "
            +"  ,now()," + ConfigDB.agents_selenium_id + ", 1420610569, " +ConfigDB.campaign_ticket + ",0, -1)  ";

}
```

I believe you know how to establish a DataBase Connection and insert record.
If not reply back to me, I'll share the code snippet for that.
Hope this resolves your issue.